# Gradle: Task 'run' not found in root project

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to use the task 'run' in gradle and it seems that it doesn't exist in my project.

When I type in terminal:

`$ gradle run`

I get the error message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Task 'run' not found in root project 'NA'.

I also built the project again, got "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", and it still didn't help me to commit the 'run' task.

How can I make 'run' task be useful again?

Answer (score 19):

You shouldn't need to manually create a task for run. If it's missing, it means there is something wrong with your build.gradle

In my case, my plugins was missing id 'application' and I didn't have a mainClassName declared at the end of the file. This is what my build.gradle looked like after run became an available task again:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

mainClassName = 'demo.App'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't define a task called `run`, there is no task called `run`, so you cannot call a task called `run`. Either define a task called `run` that does what you want, or use some plugin that adds a task called `run` that does what you want. For example the `application` plugin adds a task called `run`.

As you said "useful again" you can also track back what you changed from where it was working to where it it not working anymore and then undo it.

Comment: how can I define a new task in Gradle?

Comment: `task run` for more information please read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Answer (score 2):

check the directory from which you run the build, it should be the same in which the build.gradle file is located